# Can I have arrays or similar data structure as elements of a data frame?

Tags: r, time-series

I need something like below for a data frame?

```
   Label        Time          Value
    "X"       [0, 1, 2]   [1.1, 1.5, 2.1] 
    "Y"       [0, 1, 2]   [2.1, 3.1, 4.5]
    "Z"       [0, 1, 2]   [3.3, 3.5, 4.2]
```

I would like to have a data frame with a column representing time series label, another column for time attribute, and another for time series. Ideally, the lengths of the vectors/series are not equal.

If that is not possible, please advise how to best model the data where I have tens of thousands of time series of possibly varying lengths, each associated with a multi-part label.

My issue is that I have a dataframe with format:

```
ID  Type  Num  Tag  Time  Value
X    A     1    T1   0.0   1.1
             ...
X    A     1    T1   0.9   2.1
             ...
X    A     6    T4   0.0   3.1
             ...
X    A     6    T4   0.6   4.5
             ...
Y    C     5    T3   0.0   3.3
             ...
Y    C     5    T3   0.8   4.2
```

What I am looking for is something like this:

```
ID  Type  Num  Tag         Time               Value
X    A     1    T1   c(0.0, ..., 0.9)   c(1.1, ..., 2.1)
                  ...
X    A     6    T4   c(0.0, ..., 0.6)   c(3.1, ..., 4.5) 
                  ...
X    C     5    T3   c(0.0, ..., 0.8)   c(3.3, ..., 4.2) 
                  ...
```

The best I have achieved so far is to cut the vectors down to the same length, and then use each of the Time attributes as a column with values sorted under.

*** THANK YOU ***

Comment: Could you please explain why you need to convert the format?  Formatting is not modeling, after all.  What is this conversion expected to accomplish?

Comment: Thanx for the quick response ... The employer prefers it that way. 1. It is apparently a bit more straightforward to consume the data in the target form for clustering algorithms, e.g., `tsclust(...)`, working with `list` of time series!!! 2. In the original form, the PK is essentially (ID, Type, Num, Time) while in the target format, PK is (ID, Type, Num) which seems more reasonable to me as well. I need to cluster the list of series separately for each Type, and based on say count of Tags in each cluster, somehow tag each cluster accordingly!!! Wierd, Ey?!

Comment: How about `data.frame(Label=c("X","Y","Z"), Time=I(list(0:2, 0:2, 0:2)), Value=I(list(c(1.1, 1.5, 2.1), c(2.1, 3.1, 4.5), c(3.3, 3.5, 4.2))))` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can always store a list under a data.frame, but maybe try something like below:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

dat = data.frame(ID=rep(c("X","Y"),c(4,2)),
Type=rep(c("A","C"),c(4,2)),
Num=rep(c(1,6,5),each=2),
Tag=rep(c("T1","T4","T3"),each=2),
Time=c(0,0.9,0,0.6,0,.8),
Value=c(1.1,2.1,3.1,4.5,3.3,4.2))

dat %>% nest(data=c(Value,Time))
# A tibble: 3 x 5
  ID    Type    Num Tag   data            
  <fct> <fct> <dbl> <fct> <list>          
1 X     A         1 T1    <tibble [2 × 2]>
2 X     A         6 T4    <tibble [2 × 2]>
3 Y     C         5 T3    <tibble [2 × 2]>
```

You can access the data like this:

```
dat_nested = dat %>% nest(data=c(Value,Time))
dat_nested$data[[1]]
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  Value  Time
  <dbl> <dbl>
1   1.1   0  
2   2.1   0.9
```